# Valgrind - Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm getting valgrind errors from 2 contexts. This is the 1st. It claims I have uninitialised values but I don't see any. Please help me understand where it's telling me the problem lies:

```
        valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./Lab4 in62.txt actual.txt
==4041== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4041== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4041== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4041== Command: ./Lab4 in62.txt actual.txt
==4041== 
==4041== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4041==    at 0x409F2C: __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:4913)
==4041==    by 0x40AE3F: bool std::operator!=<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:4950)
==4041==    by 0x407FFD: Relation::join_createMap(std::deque<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > >&, std::vector<Relation, std::allocator<Relation> >&, Rule&, int&, bool&, bool&, Tuple const&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (relation.cpp:317)
==4041==    by 0x408F87: Relation::join(std::vector<Relation, std::allocator<Relation> >&, Rule&, std::vector<Rule, std::allocator<Rule> >&) (relation.cpp:438)
==4041==    by 0x42069C: Database::ruleEvaluation(std::vector<Rule, std::allocator<Rule> >&, std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&) (database.cpp:77)
==4041==    by 0x41FA97: Database::evaluate(std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::vector<Rule, std::allocator<Rule> >&, std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (database.cpp:12)
==4041==    by 0x42822C: main (main.cpp:27)
==4041==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4041==    at 0x4C2C12F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4041==    by 0x41642A: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==4041==    by 0x414A62: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:360)
==4041==    by 0x411C7F: std::_Deque_base<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > >::_M_allocate_node() (stl_deque.h:601)
==4041==    by 0x41553C: std::_Deque_base<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > >::_M_create_nodes(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >**, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >**) (stl_deque.h:726)
==4041==    by 0x4129DE: std::_Deque_base<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > >::_M_initialize_map(unsigned long) (stl_deque.h:700)
==4041==    by 0x40EB1F: std::_Deque_base<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > >::_Deque_base() (stl_deque.h:490)
==4041==    by 0x40B337: std::deque<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::allocator<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > >::deque() (stl_deque.h:883)
==4041==    by 0x408DC3: Relation::join(std::vector<Relation, std::allocator<Relation> >&, Rule&, std::vector<Rule, std::allocator<Rule> >&) (relation.cpp:425)
==4041==    by 0x42069C: Database::ruleEvaluation(std::vector<Rule, std::allocator<Rule> >&, std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&) (database.cpp:77)
==4041==    by 0x41FA97: Database::evaluate(std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::vector<Rule, std::allocator<Rule> >&, std::vector<Predicate, std::allocator<Predicate> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (database.cpp:12)
==4041==    by 0x42822C: main (main.cpp:27)
[more errors]
==5323== 
==5323== 
==5323== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5323==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==5323==   total heap usage: 29,328 allocs, 29,327 frees, 3,430,706 bytes allocated
==5323== 
==5323== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5323==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5323==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5323==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5323==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==5323==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5323== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==5323== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==5323== 
==5323== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5323== ERROR SUMMARY: 309 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**main.cpp:25-27**

```
std::ofstream out;
std::string arg = std::string(argv[2]);
myDatabase.evaluate(myDatalogProgram.getFactsVector(),myDatalogProgram.getQueriesVector(),myDatalogProgram.getRulesVector(),myDatalogProgram.getSchemesVector(), out, arg);
```

**join:**

(relation.cpp:425 is line 6, `std::deque<strPairMap> working_tuples_deque;` from the following function)

```
Relation Relation::join(std::vector<Relation> &cur_relation_vector, Rule &cur_rule, std::vector<Rule> &rules_vector){
    bool dup_scheme_params = false;
    strIntMap new_scheme_map;
    Scheme new_scheme;
    join_MakeScheme(cur_relation_vector, dup_scheme_params, new_scheme_map, new_scheme);
    std::deque<strPairMap> working_tuples_deque; //relation.cpp:425
    std::deque<strPairMap> working_tuples_deque_final;
    std::vector<int> grand_copy_vector;
    for (int j = 0; j < cur_relation_vector.size(); j++){
        for (auto &x: cur_relation_vector.at(j).tuple_set){
            bool diff_id_found = false;
            strPairMap temp_map;
            std::vector<int> map_indeces_to_copy;
            int added_to_vector = 0;
            if (working_tuples_deque.size() == 0){
                join_createFirstMap(grand_copy_vector, working_tuples_deque, temp_map, cur_relation_vector, added_to_vector, j, x);
            }
            else{
                join_createMap(working_tuples_deque, cur_relation_vector, cur_rule, j, dup_scheme_params, diff_id_found, x, temp_map, map_indeces_to_copy, grand_copy_vector);
                join_combinePrevMapsToCurMap(diff_id_found, map_indeces_to_copy, temp_map, grand_copy_vector, cur_relation_vector, working_tuples_deque,j);
            }
        }
    }
    join_removeUnworthyMaps(working_tuples_deque, working_tuples_deque_final, grand_copy_vector, new_scheme);
    /* Create new relation with new properties */
    Relation combo_relation(cur_rule.primary_predicate.getID(),new_scheme,{});
    std::set<Tuple> temp_tuple_set;
    for (auto& o: working_tuples_deque_final){
        Tuple temp_tuple;
        for (auto& z: o){
            temp_tuple.push_back(z.second.first);
        }
        temp_tuple_set.insert(temp_tuple);
    }
    combo_relation.tuple_set = temp_tuple_set;
    return combo_relation;
}
```

**join_createMap:**

```
void Relation::join_createMap(std::deque<strPairMap> &working_tuples_deque, std::vector<Relation> &cur_relation_vector, Rule &cur_rule, int &j, bool &dup_scheme_params, bool &diff_id_found, const Tuple &x, strPairMap &temp_map, std::vector<int> &map_indeces_to_copy, std::vector<int> &grand_copy_vector){
    for (int l = 0; l < working_tuples_deque.size(); l++){
        bool add_index_to_vector = true;
        for (int k = 0; k < cur_relation_vector.at(j).scheme.size(); k++){
            /* If curent scheme param k is found in map l in working deque */
            if (working_tuples_deque.at(l).find(cur_relation_vector.at(j).scheme.at(k))->second.second != cur_relation_vector.at(j).name){ //relation.cpp:317
                diff_id_found = true;
                if (working_tuples_deque.at(l).find(cur_relation_vector.at(j).scheme.at(k)) != working_tuples_deque.at(l).end()){
                    std::string param_to_match = working_tuples_deque.at(l).find(cur_rule.predicate_vector.at(j).parameter_vector.at(k).toString())->second.first;
                    /* but if the values with the matching scheme params don't match.. */
                    if (param_to_match != x.at(k)){
                        add_index_to_vector = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            std::pair<std::string, std::string> temp_pair("","");
            temp_pair.first = x.at(k);
            temp_pair.second = cur_relation_vector.at(j).name;
            temp_map.emplace(cur_relation_vector.at(j).scheme.at(k), temp_pair);
        }
        if (add_index_to_vector == true || dup_scheme_params == false){
            map_indeces_to_copy.push_back(l);
            grand_copy_vector.push_back(l);
        }
    }
}
```

What type of variable isn't being initialized? How do we pinpoint it with the provided information?

**Update:**

I now realize that the problem lies in `relation.cpp:317`, within `join_createMap`:

```
if (working_tuples_deque.at(l).find(cur_relation_vector.at(j).scheme.at(k))->second.second != cur_relation_vector.at(j).name){...}
```

When I break things down:

```
for (int k = 0; k < cur_relation_vector.at(j).scheme.size(); k++){
/* If curent scheme param k is found in map l in working deque */
strPairMap::iterator compare_it = working_tuples_deque.at(l).find(cur_relation_vector.at(j).scheme.at(k));
std::pair<std::string,std::string> compare_pair = compare_it->second; // offending line
std::string compare_string = compare_pair.second;
if (compare_string != cur_relation_vector.at(j).name){...}
...
}
```

Valgrind targets this line:

```
std::pair<std::string,std::string> compare_pair = compare_it->second;
```

with all of the following errors:

```
Source and destination overlap in memcpy(0x5ea3040, 0x5b2c450, 95601552)
Invalid read of size 8
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this causes the error but `out` is never associated with any file. Consider using the initialization constructor `std::ofstream(const char* filename, ios_base::openmode mode)`. Or does `evaluate` open the filestream?

Comment: Do you check that `argv[2]` is set before you initialize `arg` with it?

Comment: I have     `if (argc != 3){
        return 0;
    }` as the first statement in `main` (function declaration = `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`)

Comment: I didn't have valgrind errors until I added the `join` and related functions. That's why I'm so confused as to why it's directing me to my `main`.

Comment: @muXXmit2X `out` is passed by reference a couple times and then opened. As I stated above, I've had this exact `main` as is with no valgrind errors. Only when I added `join` and related functions did these come up

Comment: `relation.cpp:425` can you include that in your post (surrounding code as well)? If included, please mark it in your posted source.

Comment: @WhozCraig Added, but I hope you see more significance in it than I do

Comment: Prolly the last question I have before I pass out form staring at this: Which of the two `.find()` invokes in `join_CreateMap` is line 317 ? I suspect the first one.

Comment: @WhozCraig I marked it for you. It's the first one. That's actually the line of code I was most suspicious of...

Comment: I am too. Were I you I would break that down into separate statements before entering the final if-test. I suspect a `second` is being pulled from an invalid iterator pair, but I'm not going to lie to you; the code is a little.. dense.. to say that with any degree of certainty.

Comment: It's not pointing you to main, it's pointing you to `relation.cpp:317` where there is some kind fo string comparison. I would suggest you compile with -O0 -ggdb3

Comment: @kfsone Forgive me for my ignorance, but how would I add those flags? I tried `g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 *.cpp -o -O0 -ggdb3 project` to no avail..#novice

Comment: @kfsone I compiled with `g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -std=c++11 *.cpp -o project` and got similar errors, pointing to the same line `317`

Comment: The -O0 tells it not to do optimizations, and the -ggdb3 tells it to make the maximum possible debug symbols in gdb format. Identify line 317 and break it up into steps.

Comment: Having identified the area at fault, can you now create a [mcve]?  Because that won't depend on any of the definitions we haven't seen, it will be possible to reproduce, and the lessons learnt can then be applied to your source.  (I suspect that the `find()` fails, returning the `end` iterator, whose `second` isn't valid...)

Comment: @TobySpeight That was exactly it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line # was `relation.cpp:317`, *not* `main.cpp:27`. (Valgrind traces from the source of the problem up to the broadest scope.) The `find` function sometimes returned `working_tuples_deque.at(l).end()`. The code then went on to access `.end()`'s `second` element, which is invalid. That is where the Valgrind error originates.

As for the solution, I first initialized a separate `std::string` (`compare_string`). I then used an `if` statement to only reassign `compare_string` if the `find` did not return an `.end()` iterator (i.e. if the `find` function actually found something).

Result:

```
std::string compare_string = "";
strPairMap::iterator compare_it = working_tuples_deque.at(l).find(cur_relation_vector.at(j).scheme.at(k));
if (compare_it != working_tuples_deque.at(l).end()){
std::pair<std::string,std::string> compare_pair = compare_it->second;
compare_string = compare_pair.second;
}
```

cred: all commentators